# WHY is there conflict between python versions?

Tags: python3

I know that ubuntu 18.04 LTS needs python 3.6 for doing a lot of its stuff, but I need to run a lot of python 3.7 applications and I don't get that why there is a conflict between them, I had to go over all non-running programs in `/usr/bin` and change the line `#!/usr/bin/python3` to `#!/usr/bin/python3.6` and I'm not sure if there are some more files I should change, and I'm worried someday my PC won't boot up 'cause of that :(

Is there a way to make that conflict go away and use only python3 command for everything?

P.S. I did a lot of searching and came up with nothing so if this is a duplicate question I'm sorry

Thank you all in advance :)

Edit:

This is the error log output when I run a system program with python3.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

It's also the same if I run an app that needs 3.7 with the 3.6 version.

Comment: Keep good notes on each program changed. If system breaks boot with live usb and selectively reverse changes.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yeah I forgot that Linux has such abilities, that's a very good idea in case I had to change them all, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am not 100% sure what conflict you encounter. Why did you need to change those files in /usr/bin to use 3.6? What errors did you get and what is python3 pointing to right now?

The 'python3' is usually just a link, a pointer, to a particular python version on the system. If you need to work with different python versions there are a few different ways to do so. I will mention three that I commonly use:

1. Use a virtual environment like conda. When you install conda you basically create a manager for virtual environments where you can install python modules or even python/pip versions without any impact to the outside system. I suggest you go check conda, especially if you are worried that you will break your system by changing python stuff.
2. Run your scripts with a particular python version like

   python3.7 my_script.py

If you really want to use python3, you can just make an alias in your ~/.bashrc (or ~/.zshrc etc)

```
alias python3="/usr/bin/python3.7"
```

To check what binaries respond to the python command run

```
whereis python
```

This will give you the paths to all binaries, you can use these to make an alias like above. You can also use these to get more precise info:

```
whereis python3
which python3
which python3.7
```

3. Add shebangs to your scripts and make them executable, this is maybe less portable and you seem to know about it already.

Comment: the problem is I use Github projects a lot and some of them only work with a particular version of python, and they all used `#!usr/bin/python3` it's not me who insist on using only python3 command it's them, they have only one version installed when making those programs so they don't worry about others, now I either have to change it in the old ones or in the new ones, BTW I'm currently running on Windows, I will soon edit my question and provide you with the error log when running with the version not supposed to.